# Username and password dialogbox pops up when authorized user opens a word doc online

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, iis, ms-word

A web application developed in ASP.net deployed on IIS. A user has logged on the web application with correct username and password. A dialogbox pops up asking user to enter username and password when clicking open button in order to open the document online. The link code is like:
< a href="Manual/readme.dot" target="new">Read Me< /a>

How can make the dialogbox asking authorized user to enter username and password disappears?

More Info:

1. Document can be viewed successfully even click cancel button in the pop up window with IE7.
2. When browsing with Firefox, there is no problem. That is to say, there is no dialogbox asking user to enter username and password pops up.
3. No problem when viewing PDF file online.

Comment: I've found a solution. Hope the solution can help others.
IIS -> Authentifications -> Windows Authentifications -> Providers -> Remove negotiate, just keep NTLM

Answer (score 0):

On your manual, you can load JavaScript With this method:

> function openWin()
>
> {
>
> > myWindow = window.open("","myWindow","width=200,height=100");    // Opens a new window
>
> }
>
> function closeWin()
>
> {
>
> > myWindow.close();
>
> }

Comment: what's the purpose of doing so?